# What's the Interaction between DS_MODALFRAME and WS_THICKFRAME?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Working with an existing project, my rc file's regenerating the flags on every dialog I modify, then loading up. The previous flags were:

```
DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
```

and after the regen, it turns into:

```
DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
```

This translates to "Dialog Frame" in the designer, when the original intent was that the window should be resizable (WS_THICKFRAME). It seems fine just to set it to "Resizable", but that gives me:

```
DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
```

Note the lack of "DS_MODALFRAME" in the above.

**Is there a reason that no VS2010 setting will get me both of these, and what effect will the lack of DS_MODALFRAME have on the dialog?**

Alternatively, which cunningly hidden VS toggle do I have to switch to stop DS_MODALFRAME being removed?

Comment: They are just incompatible frame choices.  You can have a modal frame or a thick frame, you can't have both.  Surely nothing actually goes wrong at run time?  It isn't clear why you need to fix anything.

Comment: @HansPassant It's simply that they were previously both set, and I wasn't sure if this was a change to the designer, or if the file had been hand-edited before I got to it. Certainly I needed to fix the fact that the designer was "resetting" the windows to "Dialog Frame" and removing the WS_THICKFRAME resizability, my concern was that removing the modal flag would subtly change behaviour. Thanks for clearing that up!